# Unable to select a non sequential column Vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to convert columns D to F and H into percentage Format after row 5 in VBA using the following code:

`.Range(.Range("D5:F5, H5"), vRng).NumberFormat = "0.00%"`

**It will work on columns D to F, not H**.

Also, `vRng = .Range("A5", .Range("A" &.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))`

Comment: Try using `Range("D5:F" & vRng & ", H5:H" & vRng)`

Comment: vRng is not the last row number, it is a range

Comment: What does vRng point at - and what is the overall range address you'd expect it to format?

Comment: From A5 to A8 in my sheet

Comment: Try using @cybernetic.nomad 's formula, only using lRow from `lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` or suppose you could even use `lRow = vRng.Rows.Count + 4`

Comment: Can you post your answer for future readers? @cybernetic.nomad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Range("D5:F" & lRow & ", H5:H" & lRow)
```

Where `lRow` is:

```
lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```